# How do I add an attribute to a SOAP header with Savon?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, ws-addressing

I need to add this attribute (**xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"**) to the soap header, like this:

```
<env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
</env:Header>
```

How do I do this, using Savon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to make another workaround to the problem in my case, since my endpoint would accept this:

```
<env:Header>
  <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">value</wsa:Action>
</env:Header>
```

---

Investigating the original question, here's the response from the Savon creator:

"hey magne,

looking at the code which creates the header and body tags, it doesn't seem
possible to add any attributes/namespaces without monkey-patching right now:

https://github.com/rubiii/savon/blob/v0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/xml.rb#L151

if you still need this feature, please open a ticket and i'll see what i can do:
https://github.com/rubiii/savon/issues

i'm currently very involved in taking a new approach to improve the library,
so i'm not sure when i'll be able to solve your problem. but ... i hacked together
a small monkey-patch that should help until this feature is implemented:

https://gist.github.com/1698636

cheers,
daniel"

---

Comment: Anything changed since then? - did you create an issue in the end?

Comment: @Hackeron I think I just used the aforementioned workaround, and didn’t create an issue/ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own namespace to the request like this:

```
resp = client.request :soap_action do
    soap.namespace['xmlns:wsa'] = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'
end
```

Comment: I know, but that won't add the attribute to the header in question. (And that's important for my soap request to be accepted by the other end).

Answer (score 0):

foo = client.request do
  soap.header['xmlns:wsa'] = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'
end

Comment: No, this would generate this:
`<env:Header>     <xmlns:wsa>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing</xmlns:wsa></env:Header>`